# How could this question be rephrased to be non-opinion based?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I understand that [this question](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/127/comprehensive-rules-for-noun-case-endings) is phrased in a way where there seems to be no single correct answer. However, the answers to the question do provide useful information and I may want to ask similar questions in the future. What would be the correct way to retitle/rephrase the question so that the accepted answer still answers the question but the question is more along the lines of something acceptable on a stack exchange site.

Answer (score 1):

As for me the question is too huge and almost unreadable. I would split it into several small questions (e.g. separated by single noun case). Also it's not clear to me what all those tables about. Maybe when a person is familiar with those kinds of tables it is easy to see the problem, however I don't understand how to use them as a reference for case usage. So I cannot find counter-examples or gather my suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

As for me, I think the phrasing "What corrections could I make to this table" tends to be interpreted as asking for personal opinion. And not the personal opinion about the language, but rather the personal opinion about formatting of your table. I'd better say "What are mistakes (related to case endings) in this table?".

Additionally, [per Artemix](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/89/4), it's hard to understand what these tables are to mean. Although I *did* guess their meaning (even without the key), still I confirm that, due to quite untypical representation and over-laconic key, it's not trivial to guess. I can edit your questions by enhancing the key (to be more understandable from Ukrainian point of view), if you wish.

BTW, typically in schools table for noun/adjective endings look something like this:

```
Nouns:                                Adjectives:
  ❙  1-st ❙  2-nd ❙  3-rd ❙  4-th ❙   ❙ m ❙ f ❙ n ❙ pl❙
  ❙ s ❘ pl❙ s ❘ pl❙ s ❘ pl❙ s ❘ pl❙   ❙   ❙   ❙   ❙   ❙
――+―――+―――+―――+―――+―――+―――+―――+―――+   +―――+―――+―――+―――+
N ❙ … ❘ … ❙ … ❘ … ❙ … ❘ … ❙ … ❘ … ❙   ❙ … ❙ … ❙ … ❙ … ❙
G ❙ … ❘ … ❙ … ❘ … ❙ … ❘ … ❙ … ❘ … ❙   ❙ … ❙ … ❙ … ❙ … ❙
D ❙ … ❘ … ❙ … ❘ … ❙ … ❘ … ❙ … ❘ … ❙   ❙ … ❙ … ❙ … ❙ … ❙
A ❙ … ❘ … ❙ … ❘ … ❙ … ❘ … ❙ … ❘ … ❙   ❙ … ❙ … ❙ … ❙ … ❙
I ❙ … ❘ … ❙ … ❘ … ❙ … ❘ … ❙ … ❘ … ❙   ❙ … ❙ … ❙ … ❙ … ❙
L ❙ … ❘ … ❙ … ❘ … ❙ … ❘ … ❙ … ❘ … ❙   ❙ … ❙ … ❙ … ❙ … ❙
V ❙ … ❘ … ❙ … ❘ … ❙ … ❘ … ❙ … ❘ … ❙   ❙ … ❙ … ❙ … ❙ … ❙
```

Answer (score 0):

I mostly agree with @Artemix, but let me put it this way:

1. Your question is too broad. "Is there anything wrong with thins table?" invites for an **open-ended set of suggestions**.
2. The table is a natural result of your way of thinking. To understand what each row/column/record means, we need to **decompile** your table and try grasping your vision.
   It's okay if I were asked to **grasp the understanding of my language teacher**, since they:

   - know the thing deeply;
   - have already spent a considerable time for research, so there's a greater chance that their table is more or less logical;
   - have teacher's education to be able to convey what they mean;
3. yes, most of us are native speakers of Ukrainian, so it is easier for us to understand the whole table, but I sincerely doubt that **another language learner** can understand a question and possible write an answer.

So, you may try:

- maybe, don't change this very question because the changes would be drastic (and invalidate some existing answers). What's done, is done; if some answers were useful, it's yours (don't forget to pick up an "accepted answer")

  - BTW, inability to pick an "accepted answer" is a red flag about the broadness of the question itself;
- split your future questions in smaller parts;
- be specific. Narrow down your questions so that the "brief" answer would take 2-3 paragraphs (TL/DR can be of any size as it may include arguments and explanation);
- ask one question a time;